# Use std::variant as class member and apply visitor

Tags: c++, std, variant

I'm trying to use std::variant as a class member variable and then use operator overloading so that the two `Variants` of this class can use the operator `plus` to produce a new variable. The problem is that std::get does not work as I thought and so I cannot retrieve the correct (hardcoded) string types so that the `AddVisitor` struct is used.

I get a compilation error that says: `no matching function for call to ‘get<0>(std::basic_string&)’`

Also is there a way that `operator+` function detects the type without `if-else` statements?

I have already checked a lot of answers in SO including ones that answer questions about similar Boost functionality, but I cannot get it to work.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <string>
#include "stdafx.h"


using Variant = std::variant<int, std::string>;

template<typename T>
struct AddVisitor
{
    T operator()(T v1, T v2)
    {
        return v1 + v2;
    }
};

class Var
{
    Variant v;

public:

    template<typename T>
    Var(T value) : v(value) {}

    Var operator+(Var& val)
    {
        // PROBLEM: This is a hard coded example that I want to use, so that concatenation of two strings happens.
        return std::visit(AddVisitor<std::string>(), std::get<std::string>(v), std::get<std::string>(val.get()));
       // Is there a way to get the correct type without if-else statements here?
    }

   Variant get()
   {
     return v;
   }
};

int main()
{
    Var x("Hello "), y("World");

    // The expected output is this:
    Var res = x + y;

    return 0;
}
```

I expect to be able to use the plus operator and concatenate two strings or two integers and create a new `Var` variable.

Comment: The arguments to `std::visit` after the first are supposed to be variants. And `std::get<std::string>(v)` is not a variant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so there are a few things to talk about.

First, the visitor for `std::visit` with more than one variant argument should accept all combinations of variant types. In your case it should accept:

- `(string, string)`
- `(string, int)`
- `(int, int)`
- `(int, string)`

If for you only `string, string` and `int, int` are valid you still need to accept the other combinations for the code to compile, but you can throw in them.

Next, the visitor shouldn't be templated. Instead the `operator()` should be templated or overloaded for all the above combinations.

So here is `AddVisitor`:

```
struct AddVisitor
{
    auto operator()(const std::string& a, const std::string& b) const -> Variant
    {
        return a + b;
    }
    auto operator()(int a, int b) const -> Variant
    {
        return a + b;
    }

    // all other overloads invalid
    template <class T, class U>
    auto operator()(T, U) const -> Variant
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument{"invalid"};
    }
};
```

It's not clear from documentation what the overloads can return, but I couldn't make it compile unless all return `Variant`. Fortunately the compiler errors are ***[TREMENDOUSLY HELPFULL](https://godbolt.org/z/ZjQBuF)*** . (I need to check the standard).

Next, when you call `std::visit` you need to pass the `variant`s you have.

So the final code is this:

```
auto operator+(Var& val) -> Var
{
    return std::visit(AddVisitor{}, get(), val.get());
}
```

And you can indeed use it like you want:

```
Var res = x + y;
```

Another issue with your code is that `get` makes unnecessary copies. And copies of `std::variant` are not cheap to make. So I suggest:

```
auto get() const -> const Variant&  { return v; }
auto get() -> Variant&  { return v; }
```

Comment: Thank you a lot @bolov for your help and suggestions! Passing and returning a Variant was the solution. Can you please explain how the compiler knows how get the string or int from the Variant? I thought that I had to explicitly use std::get<>() to find the type and use it in Visitor.

Comment: @user1798707 `std::variant` stores an index of the active type